# how to correctly download tomcat 6 on centos 5.5

Tags: linux, unix, tomcat6, centos5

i am a big confused about how to install tomcat 6 on centos 5.5 final.

this is what i am trying to do:

```
# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
# wget http://jpackage.org/jpackage50.repo
# yum install tomcat6 tomcat6-webapps tomcat6-admin-webapps
```

but when i type the widget command, this is what i get:

```
Resolving www.jpackage.org... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.jpackage.org'
```

could anyone kindly show me the right way please. really in trouble at the moment with this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your machine isn't connected or has no proper means to resolve names: try `ping 212.85.158.22` to see, whether you can reach the internets at all.

Comment: you are correct! my machine was not connected. thanks man

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have the troubles with your dns servers or local name resolver. 
You can use dig to determine ip-adderss of www.jpackage.org and then add it to your local /etc/hosts file.